# Ubuntu server 22.04.1 ARM64 problem with browsers

Tags: browser

I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu Server 22.04.1 ARM64 created with UTM and I'm working on a Macbook Pro M1 Pro.
I create the machine correctly, install desktop and initially everything works correctly but I have a persistent problem, neither Firefox nor Chromium work for me. When I run either of the two browsers, the icon loads, the message "Firefox Web Browser Mozilla firefox is ready" appears, but it remains stuck in a loop and doesn't display any pages (the same thing happens with Chromium). Any idea what problem I might be having?

Comment: Run `chromium` or `firefox` in the terminal and post the output.

Comment: Gtk-Message: 15:43:41.763: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it. [GFX-]: glxtest: VA-API test failed: failed to initialise VAAPI connection.
ATENNTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overrriden by enviroment